# C# casting, Indexof

Tags: c#, arrays, casting, indexof

I'm *new to programming* (for 5 days). I wrote this code but index is always `-1` (when `2` is expected) and I couldn't fix it.

My teacher wrote me just that:

```
Casting, Array.IndexOf(geburtsjahr, (int)1966);
```

I tried but still same.

This is my relevant code:

```
var geburtsjahr = new short[4] { 1998, 1992, 1966, 2006 }; 

// Expected: 2, Actual: -1
int index = Array.IndexOf(geburtsjahr, (int)1966);

Console.WriteLine(index);
```

I tried to see right `index` number (should be `2`).

Comment: Looks more like [tag:C#] to me.

Comment: It is C# not C++

Comment: Please state the problem you are trying to solve. From code it is not clearly understandable what you are trying to do.

Comment: As `geburtsjahr` is a `short[]`, you should try `(short)1966` instead of `(int)1966`, which in fact does nothing. Obviously.

Comment: `int index = Array.IndexOf(geburtsjahr, (short)1966);`

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your code is that you have `short[]` array and `int` value to find in it and .net can't do *implicit cast* from `int` to `short` for you. There are [several](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-7.0) overload `Array.IndexOf` implementations:

- [Array.IndexOf(T[], T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-7.0#system-array-indexof-1(-0()-0)): will not be used, since .net can't cast `int` to `short` or `short[]` to `int[]` and come to a single generic `T`
- [Array.IndexOf(Array, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-7.0#system-array-indexof(system-array-system-object)): this will be called

In case of `Array.IndexOf(Array, Object)` .net looks for an *object* (*boxed* `int` value) in an array of objects. The array contains `short` values (which can be *boxed*, but still `short`), not `int`, so .net can't find `int`.

Possible corrections:

1. Make `geburtsjahr` have `int` values:

```
var geburtsjahr = new int[4] { 1998, 1992, 1966, 2006 };
```

2. Search for `short`:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(geburtsjahr, (short)1966);
```

3. Let .net do the cast for you (`1966` will be of type `short`):

```
int index = Array.IndexOf<short>(geburtsjahr, 1966);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you do either of these:

(1)

```
var geburtsjahr = new short[4] { 1998, 1992, 1966, 2006 };
int index = Array.IndexOf(geburtsjahr, (short)1966);
```

(2)

```
var geburtsjahr = new int[4] { 1998, 1992, 1966, 2006 };
int index = Array.IndexOf(geburtsjahr, (int)1966); //or just 1966 without the cast.
```

The issue is that there is no `int` of any value in an array of `short` values, no matter what the numbers represent to us humans.